# Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError

Tags: java, jar

I have used `xuggle library` in my project to trans code the video from `mp4 to flv`.
I have used `slf4j libraries` also to support logging end.

```
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaViewer;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;

public class TranscodingExample {

    private static final String inputFilename = "E:\\VIDEO\\Facebook.mp4";
    private static final String outputFilename = "E:\\VIDEO\\Facebook.flv";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create a media reader
        IMediaReader mediaReader = 
               ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);
        
        // create a media writer
        IMediaWriter mediaWriter = 
               ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename, mediaReader);

        // add a writer to the reader, to create the output file
        mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter);
        
        // create a media viewer with stats enabled
        IMediaViewer mediaViewer = ToolFactory.makeViewer(true);
        
        // add a viewer to the reader, to see the decoded media
        mediaReader.addListener(mediaViewer);

        // read and decode packets from the source file and
        // and dispatch decoded audio and video to the writer
        while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null) ;

    }

}
```

Here I am getting an error

```
"Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError.".
```

I have used both jar files as libraries in order to solve logging problems.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: If you are using log4j, you could simply exclude the `log4j-over-slf4j.jar`. In theory using log4j and hacking other code to route the log4j calls to slf4j can lead to recursion and hence the strict check.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

So you have to exclude conflict dependencies. Try this:

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

This solved same problem with slf4j and Dozer.

Comment: That is because some dependencies that you add will have the logs libraries of their choice and so cause conflicts.

Comment: You should also remove the log4j jar that has been added to your classpath. Check your lib folder of storm. Atleast it was the case with me.

Comment: I could only get a SpringBoot application after I added that.

Comment: In which <dependency> tag do we add this exclusion? I've tried in the 'spring-boot-starter-web' exclusions but did not work. Which dependency?

Comment: This is the exclusion that worked for me: <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>*</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

Comment: In which <dependency> tag do we add this exclusion?

Comment: To figure out which dependency to put the exclusion in, run `mvn dependency:tree`. Search the results for `slf4j-log4j12`. Whichever artifact within the module's pom that's bringing in the log4j12 dependency is the artifact you want to put the exclusion in.

Answer (score 4):

Encountered a similar error, this how I resolved it:

1. Access Project explorer view on Netbeans IDE 8.2. Proceed to your project under Dependencies hover the cursor over the log4j-over-slf4j.jar to view the which which dependencies have indirectly imported as shown below. 
   [image]
2. Right click an import jar file and select Exclude Dependency
   [image]
3. To confirm, open your pom.xml file you will notice the exclusion element as below.

[image]
4. Initiate maven clean install and run your project. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

And for SBT : `excludeDependencies += "log4j" % "log4j"`

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution

download Xuggler 5.4 here

and some more jar to make it work...

commons-cli-1.1.jar

commons-lang-2.1.jar

logback-classic-1.0.0.jar

logback-core-1.0.0.jar

slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar

[image: Reference Libraries]

You can check which dependencies xuggler needs from here:

Add this jars and xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar to your project's build path and it s ready.

**version numbers may change

Answer (score 2):

For gradle

```
compile('org.xxx:xxx:1.0-SNAPSHOT'){
    exclude module: 'log4j'
    exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SBT solution stated above did not work for me. What worked for me is excluding `slf4j-log4j12`

```html
//dependencies with exclusions
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    //depencies
).map(_.exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-log4j12"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude `log4j-over-slf4j`

```xml
<dependency>
    ....
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```