# How do I write this Maven exclusion code in Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, spring-boot, betamax

I'm trying to use the latest (master) version of Betamax in a Spring Boot project, and I'm getting the error `SLF4J: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError.`.

So I looked at the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117720/detected-both-log4j-over-slf4j-jar-and-slf4j-log4j12-jar-on-the-class-path-pree), and it says to exclude conflict dependencies by doing this:

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

But my project uses Gradle, so I have to convert that to Gradle, and I really don't know what I'm doing. I looked at [this post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependency/2119) and tried messing around with it like

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile('org.slf4j') {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
}
```

but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me figure out the right syntax? I'd really appreciate any help.

If it helps at all, my dependencies block currently looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.2.1.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.3'
    testCompile 'co.freeside.betamax:betamax-proxy:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    testCompile 'co.freeside.betamax:betamax-junit:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:1.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
    compile 'com.domingosuarez.boot:spring-boot-starter-jade4j:0.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.5'
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
    runtime 'net.kencochrane.raven:raven-log4j2:6.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Which dependency is pulling in slf4j-log4j12? I don't see it. Anyway, that is the dependency you want to exclude from (not org.slf4j). For example, if it's raven-log4j2, then `runtime('net.kencochrane.raven:raven-log4j2:6.0.0') { exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12' }`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, guys. I was able to fix the error by following Don Bottstein's advice and doing this:

```
testCompile('co.freeside.betamax:betamax-proxy:2.0-SNAPSHOT') {
    exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
testCompile('co.freeside.betamax:betamax-junit:2.0-SNAPSHOT') {
    exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is :

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.gradle.test.excludes:api:1.0") {
        exclude group: "org.springframework", module: "spring-core"
    }
}
```

Where:

- *org.gradle.test.excludes:api:1.0* is a groupId:artifactId:version
- *group: "org.springframework", module: "spring-core"* is a group: groupId, module: artifactId

Comment: I got this error: `Could not GET 'http://oss.jfrog.org/oss-snapshot-local/org/gradle/test/excludes/api/1.0/api-1.0.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict`

Comment: It was an example, you have to replace values with the info you have.