# Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar

Tags: java, jar, log4j, slf4j, geotools

I have used geotools library, in my project I have added all the dependencies to the buildpath

Downloaded the libraries from [Sourseforge.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geotools/files/) Added the same to the library, When I try to execute the application, I am getting the below error.

```
    SLF4J: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. 
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.filePathToKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabaseObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.DirectEpsgFactory.getConnection(DirectEpsgFactory.java:3529)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:437)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:114)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:218)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:100)
    at org.geotools.util.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:808)
    at org.geotools.util.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:631)
    at org.geotools.util.factory.FactoryRegistry.lambda$getFactories$0(FactoryRegistry.java:300)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.lambda$initPartialTraversalState$0(StreamSpliterators.java:294)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.fillBuffer(StreamSpliterators.java:206)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.doAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:161)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:300)
    at java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.hasNext(Spliterators.java:681)
    at org.geotools.util.LazySet.isEmpty(LazySet.java:98)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ManyAuthoritiesFactory.<init>(ManyAuthoritiesFactory.java:115)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:114)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.<init>(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:67)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:253)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:533)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:447)
    at org.geotools.dev.SelectApp.fromBytes(SelectApp.java:153)
    at org.geotools.dev.SelectApp.selectAll(SelectApp.java:81)
    at org.geotools.dev.SelectApp.main(SelectApp.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate Log4j Logger
    at org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger.getLog(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger.getLog(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.FileUtil.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:39)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:49)
    ... 42 more
```

What I have tried sofar…,

as suggested in this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117720/detected-both-log4j-over-slf4j-jar-and-slf4j-log4j12-jar-on-the-class-path-pree), I have added the exclusions. Still having the same error.

I don't have any dependency with them, even I have removed both the jar files, still the error remains same!!

my Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
           <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
           <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
           <artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <packaging>jar</packaging>
           <name>tutorial</name>
           <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
           <properties>
              <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
              <geotools.version>24-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
           </properties>
           <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                 <groupId>junit</groupId>
                 <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                 <version>4.11</version>
                 <scope>test</scope>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
                 <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
                 <version>${geotools.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
                 <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
                 <version>${geotools.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
              <!-- <dependency>
                 <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                 <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                 <version>1.2.17</version>
              </dependency> -->
           </dependencies>
           <repositories>
              <repository>
                 <id>osgeo</id>
                 <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
                 <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
                 <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                 </snapshots>
                 <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                 </releases>
              </repository>
              <repository>
                 <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
                 <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
                 <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/</url>
                 <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                 </snapshots>
                 <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                 </releases>
              </repository>
           </repositories>
           <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                 <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                 <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                 <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
           <build>
              <plugins>
                 <plugin>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                       <source>1.8</source>
                       <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                 </plugin>
              </plugins>
           </build>
        </project>
```

In my maven dependencies by default I got `slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar`

Comment: And how are you doing the exclusions?

Comment: Have you checked the classpath of your project Maybe the IDE you are using still have the both files there. Excluding it from pom should have worked though.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my `geotools` library to 23.x, then all my issues got resolved.